# UITabBarControllerDelegate method not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller which has 4 tabs, I want: when tap the 4th tab(a dummy viewcontroller), it will present a new viewcontroller without showing the dummy VC.

here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"called");
    AskQuestionViewController *AQVC = [[AskQuestionViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AskQuestionViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3])
    {
        [self presentViewController:AQVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

and in my viewDidLoad method, i did set the delegate.`self.tabBarController.delegate = self;`

however, for some reason, this method is not being called.
can anyone help?

Comment: did you get any warning at the line delgate=self?

Comment: @T_77 no i didn't. In my .h file, i did add the UITabaBarControllerDelegate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

because this class is a `tabBarController`, clearly a `UITabBarController` class doesn't have a property called `tabBarController`.

So I just changed `self.tabBarController.delegate = self` to `self.delegate = self`

Comment: This is working, but I don't know this is good solution or not?

Comment: @Gellert you are my hero :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

> Tells the delegate that the user selected an item in the tab bar.

```
- tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
```

> Asks the delegate whether the specified view controller should be made active.

Comment: anyway you need to tell the delegate that you tapped 4th tab,you can call the view controller after you tap on the 4th tab. Try this and let me know if any issues occurred

Comment: I changed the self.tabBarController.delegate = self to self.delegate = self.

Comment: because this class is a tabBarController, clearly a UITabBarController class doesn't have a property called tabBarController.

Comment: Where are you calling this delegate method?

Comment: you need to assign delegate in viewDidLoad() and If your class is implementing UITabBarController do self.delegate = self rather than self.tabController?.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who had the issue with `UITabBarController` delegate with [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero). the problem is with `Hero` transition delegate and solution is to put your tabBarController in a `ViewController` as a `container`. Then setup `Hero` on the container and problem solves.

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [...]
let container = UIViewController()
container.addChild(tabBarController)
container.view.addSubview(tabBarController.view)
tabBarController.didMove(toParent: container)
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: container.view.frame.width, height: container.view.frame.height)
container.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
container.hero.isEnabled = true
container.modalAnimationType = .slide(direction: .left)
rootViewController.present(container, animated: true, completion: nil)
```